# How to detect whether the camera that is chosen by the user is real or not, within the web browser?

Tags: javascript, camera

[image]

I need to detect whether the camera that is chosen by the user is real or not, in the web browser.
Using JavaScript I can get label and id of the camera but `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label` is changeable by the user and `stream.getVideoTracks()[0].id` is not unique and it also changes session to session. 
With a C# app, I think that I can detect that it is real or not by looking at the property PNPDeviceID. For a real camera it is a value like USB\VID... For a fake camera (in my case AlterCam) its value is ROOT\IMAGE\0000.

But in my case I need to detect it within the web browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: try to use [MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)

Comment: There is no foolproof strategy, you're sandboxed by the browser so there's no way of knowing if it's 'real'

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I tried that also. As far as I understand, it does not give any extra information.